# Get information from a xml imdb response with no tags

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, imdb

I'm working on a movie data base, getting responses from imdb. I'm getting the response in a xml format, but it has no tags, just the information mixed. How can I get each of the data in there?

Here's how the respone shows up:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root response="True">
 <movie title="Batman" year="1989" rated="PG-13" released="23 Jun 1989" runtime="126 min" genre="Action, Adventure" director="Tim Burton" writer="Bob Kane (Batman characters), Sam Hamm (story), Sam Hamm (screenplay), Warren Skaaren (screenplay)" actors="Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl" plot="Gotham City. Crime boss Carl Grissom (Jack Palance) effectively runs the town but there's a new crime fighter in town - Batman (Michael Keaton). Grissom's right-hand man is Jack Napier (Jack Nicholson), a brutal man who is not entirely sane... After falling out between the two Grissom has Napier set up with the Police and Napier falls to his apparent death in a vat of chemicals. However, he soon reappears as The Joker and starts a reign of terror in Gotham City. Meanwhile, reporter Vicki Vale (Kim Basinger) is in the city to do an article on Batman. She soon starts a relationship with Batman's everyday persona, billionaire Bruce Wayne." language="English, French, Spanish" country="USA, UK" awards="Won 1 Oscar. Another 8 wins & 26 nominations." poster="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="69" imdbRating="7.6" imdbVotes="302,842" imdbID="tt0096895" type="movie" />
 </root>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are definitely tags in that response, otherwise it wouldn't be valid XML. I see a `<root>` tag and a `<movie>` tag. I think what you're really asking is how to access the `<movie>` tag's attributes (e.g. `title="Batman"`, `year="1989"`, `rated="PG-13"`, etc.) Please see the proposed duplicate for an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to your question

```
xmlRaw="""< ?xml
version = "1.0"
encoding = "UTF-8"? > < root
response = "True" >
< movie
title = "Batman"
year = "1989"
rated = "PG-13"
released = "23 Jun 1989"
runtime = "126 min"
genre = "Action, Adventure"
director = "Tim Burton"
writer = "Bob Kane (Batman characters), Sam Hamm (story), Sam Hamm (screenplay), Warren Skaaren (screenplay)"
actors = "Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl"
plot = "Gotham City. Crime boss Carl Grissom (Jack Palance) effectively runs the town but there's a new crime fighter in town - Batman (Michael Keaton). Grissom's right-hand man is Jack Napier (Jack Nicholson), a brutal man who is not entirely sane... After falling out between the two Grissom has Napier set up with the Police and Napier falls to his apparent death in a vat of chemicals. However, he soon reappears as The Joker and starts a reign of terror in Gotham City. Meanwhile, reporter Vicki Vale (Kim Basinger) is in the city to do an article on Batman. She soon starts a relationship with Batman's everyday persona, billionaire Bruce Wayne."
language = "English, French, Spanish"
country = "USA, UK"
awards = "Won 1 Oscar. Another 8 wins & 26 nominations."
poster = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"
metascore = "69"
imdbRating = "7.6"
imdbVotes = "302,842"
imdbID = "tt0096895"
type = "movie" / >
< / root >"""

def getValue(xml, value):
    textString = xmlRaw.split('\n')
    for line in textString:
        if value in line:
            returnData = line
    return returnData

print (getValue(xmlRaw, 'title'))
print (getValue(xmlRaw, 'year'))
print (getValue(xmlRaw, 'rated'))
print (getValue(xmlRaw, 'released'))

#add more as you need the data
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens here if you do `getValue(xmlRaw, 'imdb')`? What if an attribute's value contains the name of another attribute, e.g. if we had `plot="After being released from prison..."` (which says "released"). The only proper way to parse XML is to use a full-featured XML parser.

Comment: Yes you are correct. As with any solution error and bug checking would need to be implemented. Also I am aware an xml parser is a better solution. I just wanted to give a quick and easy way to retrieve his/her data.